# Building drawable images to use on a surface canvas on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have some images (.png format) that I use as drawables on the surface of canvas in my android app.  The problem I have is mspaint only allows a rectangular image file, so whatever I draw on the screen always shows up in a box.

Is there a (free) program or way I can edit the png files so that when they are drawn on the surface of my canvas, they are drawn to shape?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) you can create a png with a transparent background and only draw as solid the shape you want to show.